# Kafka-kinesis connector error: Failed to start task XXX-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:652)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-kinesis

I'm following the tutorial on the kinesis-kafka GitHub site https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-kafka-connector

I've used maven to compile the kinesis-kaka-connector.jar class library so far and I am attempting to run the connector.

I have not exported the path to kinesis-kaka-connector.jar to CLASSPATH as I do not know how exactly to do that, but instead I've added the .jar path to the worker.properties file by adding the line (similar to the apache Kafka QuickStart tutorial), seemingly correctly pointing Kafka connect to the classes.

```
plugin.path=kinesis-kafka-connector/target/kinesis-kafka-connector.jar
```

This fixed a previous error where the kinesis-kafka-connector classes couldn't be found when I tried to add the .jar file to $JAVA_HOME/lib/ext . Now,
includes an error when I use the command:

```
$ bin/connect-standalone.sh PATH/worker.properties  PATH/kinesis-firehose-kafka-connector.properties
```

The following error occurs:

```
ERROR [kinesis-kafka-connector-firehose|task-0] Failed to start task kinesis-kafka-connector-firehose-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:652)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/kinesisfirehose/model/AmazonKinesisFirehoseException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:735)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:113)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TaskConfig.<init>(TaskConfig.java:51)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:607)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startSinkTask(Worker.java:521)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.startTask(StandaloneHerder.java:392)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.createConnectorTasks(StandaloneHerder.java:385)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.createConnectorTasks(StandaloneHerder.java:379)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.updateConnectorTasks(StandaloneHerder.java:436)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.lambda$null$2(StandaloneHerder.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.model.AmazonKinesisFirehoseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:136)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 22 more
```

and finally, the last line of output is:

```
INFO Created connector kinesis-kafka-connector-firehose (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:113)
```

The connector seems to then continue running.
Has the connector actually been started though?

My kinesis firehose is connected to an S3 bucket and I don't see any records coming through. There are two conflicting outputs as shown above with the error.

Has anyone got any insight into this issue? I do not understand the NoClassDefFoundError. Is this caused by my method of pointing the Kafka-connect to the kinesis-kafka-connect.jar? I feel like that isn't the problem and I'm hoping it's just a configuration setup error, maybe my authentication or IAM policies on AWS are not configured properly. The error seems to be a firehose error.

Thanks in advance, I've tried to search other questions already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClassNotFound is a JVM class-loading (i.e. `plugin.path`) problem, unrelated to AWS / other Connector configuration.

Creating the connector is necessary before a class is actually loaded, and therefore why you also see that log.

`plugin.path` needs to be an absolute path on disk, to a folder containing all the JARs for that connector (even if there is only one)

So, try, in connect-standalone.properties

```
plugin.path=/opt/kafka-connect-plugins
```

Then in the terminal, create a new folder

```bash
$ mkdir -p /opt/kafka-connect-plugins/kinesis-connector
$ chmod -R 770 /opt/kafka-connect-plugins
```

And move plugins there

```bash
$ mv $HOME/kinesis-kafka-connector/target/*  /opt/kafka-connect-plugins/kinesis-connector
```

You shouldn't need to set CLASSPATH variable, but that would look like

```bash
$ export CLASSPATH="/path/to/files/*.jar"
$ connect-standalone.sh connect-standalone.properties kinesis.properties
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, thank you! I didn't realise there was a requirement to use absolute paths due to the apache Kafka quickstart tutorial using relative paths. In fact I do not understand why this was causing a problem in the first place.

Comment: Using relative paths will depend where you actually run the startup script. Absolute paths fix that uncertainty.